# Is it possible to get a callback when a permission is granted to an application in Android

Tags: android, android-permissions

Android M has introduced Runtime permission model.
`checkPermission()` method of Package Manager can be used to know if a permission is granted to an application.
Is it also possible to get a callback in application, when user grants/revokes permission ?
So that a feature dependent on that permission can be enabled/disabled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it also possible to get a callback in application, when user grants/revokes permission ?

If you are requesting permissions with `requestPermission()`, your callback is `onRequestPermissionResult()`.

If the user revokes permissions via Settings, your callback is `onCreate()`, as Android will terminate your process.

If the user grants permissions via Settings, you do not find out about that, until your next call to `checkSelfPermission()`. There is no callback for this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

When user grants permission via settings and comes back to the app, `onResume()` will be called. You can check for the permissions within `onResume`.

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    if (_navigatedToSettings == true) { // set this to true before you open settings
         _navigatedToSettings = false
         PermissionUtils.askForCameraAndAudioPermissions(this)
    }  
}
```